# Is there any efficient method to find the original number after the application of modulo

Tags: modulo

I'm solving a problem where I need to know the original value of the number. Is there any efficient method to find the original value of a number after modulo operation is performed.
I have seen a solution on the internet but can I know the original implementation

[Is it possible to get the original value of a number, after several multiplications **with overflow**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920754/is-it-possible-to-get-the-original-value-of-a-number-after-several-multiplicati)

Comment: Hi! Actually you've created a duplicate question. It isn't good. Please consider writing a comment to the original question answer instead.

Comment: To add the comment I need have 50 minimum reputation so that's why I have raised the question sir

Comment: What do you mean under 'original implementation'? It seems there are two answers providing complete solution with code.